# Metamask not showing localhost “7545”

Tags: dapps, dapp-development

A happy new year to you all. I am trying to make a decentralised application. Everything was going well until I came across a snag. Metamask does not show localhost "7545" which I need to connect the client facing application to the local network. I would be grateful for your guidance in this respect. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You have to configure a new network to connect to via Metamask. Open Metamask go to `settings > network > add network`! and there add your new network. If it's a local node in RPC URL put: http://127.0.0.1:7545 and choose a name for it and save. Then go on the top menu of Metamask and choose your newly created network to be the host of the communication and that's it

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: when adding a new network in Metamask it is not obvious what the Chain Id should be. How do you find the correct value?